# How do I receive Bitcoins from my clients who owe me money?

Tags: receiving

How do I receive Bitcoins from my clients who owe me money? I do not have a web site. Currently I send my clients an invoice. They discharge the invoice by sending me a check drawn on their bank checking account. Do I have to send them a Bitcoin "key" or account number of some kind?

Answer (score 4):

You send them a bitcoin address along with the invoice. Use a different address each time, so that you can tell who paid you.

Answer (score 1):

There are do-it-yourself methods (e.g., generate addresses using the bulk mode of [BitAddress.org](http://BitAddress.org) and send those out as payment addresses) but that requires a fair amount of tracking and manual effort.

You can instead use a payment processor to send out invoices.  For instance, [Coinbase offers e-mail invoices](https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/email_invoices) as well as [payment pages](https://coinbase.com/docs/merchant_tools/payment_pages), and BitPay offers a similar [payment page](https://bitpay.com/embedded-bitcoin-invoice) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Coinbase requires control of your bitcoins. You can try other services like [blockonomics](https://www.blockonomics.co) that allow you to generate P2P invoices. Or you can just directly send the client your bitcoin address/amount through email.